# Using Curl to Login to Vimeo

Tags: php, cookies, curl, authentication

I'm trying to use CURL with PHP to login to Vimeo.com, [Vimeo login](http://vimeo.com/log_in).

To provide the data for CURL to use (cookie and field data), I'm using a browser extension to read the field data off of the webpage and get the cookies. I'm then passing that data through to my server and am trying to login using curl.

I'm quite positive that the browser extension part works correctly (gets the correct data) because I can verify what it's passing with what it should be passing, and it matches correctly.

Additionally, I've used this on other sites as well, and it has no problem logging in, but on vimeo the exec returns `false`.

Any thoughts?

```
function curlpage(){
    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = $this->input->post('url');
    $data = $this->input->post('data');
    $cookie = $this->input->post('cookie');
    $method = $this->input->post('method');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
    if(strtolower($method)=="put"){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
    }
    else{
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 0);
    }
    if(strtolower($method)=="get"){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
    }
    else{
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 0);
    }
    if(strtolower($method)=="post"){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    }
    else{
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd().'/certificates/BuiltinObjectToken-EquifaxSecureCA.crt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    $error = curl_error($ch);
    $url=curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
    if(!preg_match('/^http(s)?:\/\//', $url)){
        $url = 'http://' . $url;
    }
    $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    $page = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return array('page'=>$page, 'url'=>$host, 'error'=>$error);
}
```

Here's a sample of the data I'm sending to the above function on my server (with a bogus email an password and altered cookies):

```
data=action%253Dlogin%2526service%253Dvimeo%2526email%253Dhou%2540fah.com%2526password%253Dudwt%2526token%253D6b2fc081bcdf02b1f58a390d6a3f8b83
cookie=__utma%3D18392654.1284111214.1456668252.1456678435.1456181183.3%3B__utmb%3D18302654.2.10.1454681883%3B__utmc%3D18232154%3B__utmz%3D17202654.1456675435.2.2.utmcsr%3Dgoogle%7Cutmccn%3D(organic)%7Cutmcmd%3Dorganic%7Cutmctr%3D(not%2520provided)%3B
method=POST
url=http%3A%2F%2Fvimeo.com%2Flog_in
```

Comment: I can see u r passing a Token in the cookie.. Can plz tell how did u manage to get it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vimeo, I've actually found to be a weird case for websites.  They don't set all of their cookies up front, but rather set certain cookies needed to login when the form is submitted.  So one of my problems was that I was not submitting all of the correct cookie information.

My second problem was that I was not correctly encoding my data as it was being sent.

All said and done, I now have got it to work!

Comment: Can you show the code for how you resolved this, or close the question?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ret = customSendDataByCurl("https://vimeo.com/log_in");
preg_match("/xsrft: \'(.*)\',/i",$ret,$token);
$token = $token[1];
echo "$token <hr>";

$cookie = '(copy from your browser using tamper data)... xsrft='.$token;

$headers = array(
    "Referer: https://vimeo.com/log_in",
    "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0",
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest",
    "X-Request: JSON",
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
);
$ret = customSendDataByCurl("https://vimeo.com/log_in?action=warm", "POSTDATA=email=(email url encoded)&token=".$token, $headers, $cookie);


$fields = array(
    "action" => "login",
    "service" => "vimeo",
    "email" => "(email)",
    "password" => "(pass)",
    "token" => $token,
);
$headers = array(
    "Referer: https://vimeo.com/log_in",
    "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0",
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
);
$ret = customSendDataByCurl("https://vimeo.com/log_in", http_build_query($fields), $headers, $cookie);
$ret = customSendDataByCurl("https://vimeo.com/stats/video/84142281/totals/export:csv", http_build_query($fields), $headers, $cookie);
var_export($ret);

function customSendDataByCurl($agateway, $apostfields=null, $headers=array(), $cookie="") {
    if(is_array($apostfields)) $apostfields = http_build_query($apostfields);

    $cookiesFile = 'cookies.txt';

    $ch = curl_init($agateway);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true );
    if ($headers) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0' );
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$cookiesFile);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$cookiesFile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
    if(!empty($apostfields)) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $apostfields);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    if(!$response) $response="CURL #".curl_errno($ch).": ".curl_error($ch);
    return $response;
}
```